# pandas appending values to a list in a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the below example, I want to append datas from column c to the list of values in column notes

df:

[image]

expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You must loop to work with lists in pandas DataFrame/Series:

```
for c,l in zip(df['c'], df['Notes']):
    l.append(c)
```

output:

```
    c       Notes
0   1         [1]
1   2  [12, 2, 2]
2  11    [21, 11]
```

used input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'c': [1,2,11],
                   'Notes': [[], [12,2], [21]]})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use apply :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[3, 4, 1, []], [2, 45, 2, [12, 2]], [4, 7, 11, [21]]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'Notes'])

df['Notes'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Notes'] + [x['c']], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) function:

```py
df.apply(lambda x: x["Notes"].append(x["c"]), axis=1)
```